# JIRA Release subset of features

Tags: jira

I have a set of features on the column "done" in JIRA. I want to make a release of all of them in a main version number - V.2.0. But before that there is a small feature also in the "done" section I would like to make a release from and call it -  v.1.21.

Can this be done without moving all the other features from the "done" column back to "ready to test" (previous column) and having all developers notified.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the 1.21 version to those issues by hand and create a board based on that